# ASPnet mvc6 parameter null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I had a simple test page to have a get method but the parameter that receive from view is always null, do you have any ideas?

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        //id is always null
        return View();
    }
}
```

View

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
    <input type="search" id="ida"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You input does not have a `name` attribute! `<input type="search" name="id"/>`

Comment: ok so the issue is the name! but if I have more parameter?

Comment: What do you mean? You can have as many parameters as you like.

Comment: So the role is to have the name the same the parameters name of controller?

Comment: Yes - if you have 2 inputs, one with `name="id"` and one with `name="a"` it will bind to those parameters

Comment: You have a correct answer from Josh and you should accept it. If you have a new question, then ask a new question (I have rolled back your edit)

Comment: And you could start by understanding [Html Forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
    <input type="search" id="ida"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

To:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
    <input type="search" id="id" name="id" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Add as many parameters as you'd like, or better yet make an object to accept a ViewModel. Just make sure the parameters and input names match.